# How to build the program written in python 2 into exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Please help me build the program in exe file for windows, my app is written in python 2. For this I have tried to use pyinstaller

Manual for the pyinstaller here: http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/develop/project/doc/Manual.pdf

As a result, I get a file but it is not exe

I ask you friends, explain a little bit to me on how to make this correctly

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about how it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use py2exe for building the exe for windows.

You can download py2exe from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/

You can find the tutorial here : http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial